# Replacement methode for currentSession()

Tags: wakanda

Is there a replacement for the currentSession() method that can already be used? I noticed that this method is deprecated after v11.

All the examples in the docs still use the currentSession() methode.
Ex.: http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Global-Application/Application/getSession.301-1089198.en.html

Comment: same with currentUser()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And there will be removed in v2.x.
These two global APIs are now available in the `directory` object since v1.1.0.

```
directory.currentSession
directory.currentUser
```

Source : [Wakanda API Reference](https://wakanda.github.io/wakanda-api-reference/docs/interfaces/directory.html#currentsession)

Comment: Thank you Yann, this is just what I was looking for.